# what is significance of tempspc in oracle explain plan and the measure of this is M=MB and K=KB?

Tags: oracle

what is significance of tempspc in oracle explain plan and the measure of this is M=MB and K=KB?

is there any way we can reduce this tempspc utilization in oracle query
Please find sample plan

```
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                               | 11966 |  3552K|       |   623   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                 |                               | 11966 |  3552K|       |   623   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK             |                               | 11966 |  1332K|  1968K|   623   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| BAl_ACTIVITY                  | 11966 |  1332K|       |   311   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_FIN_ACTVT_BAL_ID          | 11966 |       |       |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you edited the question and shows the explain plan results.  thanks

Comment: And please show the execution plan as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Ideally generated with `dbms_xplan.display(format => 'MEMSTATS IOSTATS LAST')` - not as a screen shot

Comment: please find sample plan for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the metrics are expressed in bytes unless a unit specifyer is provided.
TEMP tablespace is used for large SQL operations that can't be completed in memory and need to spill to disk.  For example:

1. Sorting
2. merging
3. parallel

To reduce temp:

1. You can increase the PGA to provide more memory for the SQL
   operations and thus reduce the likelihood of spilling over to temp.
2. Rewrite or tune the query to use less expensive operations.